# How to find a list of all articles published by a particular journal?

Tags: citations, literature-review, bibliometrics, reference-managers, databases

My colleagues and I are looking into ways to get a list of all articles published for the history of a given journal.  Primarily, we are looking to for a list that includes title, authors, year, volume, and issue number, but more/less information is good too.  Our primary function is to just use as a resource for various reviews that we might conduct.

I've had some success with Web of Science citation reports, but for some journals, the citation reports are incomplete or do not cover far enough back in the journal's history (the journal that I'm currently having difficulty with is published by Taylor and Francis).

Are there other resources available to generating these lists?

Comment: Have you asked your local research librarian?

Answer (score 1):

Most university libraries subscribe to many databases. Web of Science is only one. Scopus is another. And there are a huge number of databases that are more discipline specific. In pretty much all these databases you can search the source or publication name field for a particular journal. And they will enable you to export detailed bibliographic data.

Some may place limit on the number of records you can readily export.

But the basic advice is that if one database does not give you what you want, try another. My default is Scopus, but there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find this on the journal's website, you can do this with Web of Science. Go to Web of Science, then search by publication name. For example the search below would find all publications in *Nature* from 1900 to the present day.

[image]